# Unexpected output (BMP) file

Tags: c

I'll make an edge detection with Sobel operator if I managed to create a double array that keeps the pixel values of 8bit Gray-scale BMP file. After execution of program, it creates an weirdy bitmap file: What could be the missing point? Thanks for help!! Here are the [photos](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~kioutsovkm/main.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
  unsigned short bfType;
  unsigned int bfSize;
  unsigned short int bfReserved1;
  unsigned short int bfReserved2;
  unsigned int bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;


#pragma pack()
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  unsigned int biSize;
  unsigned int biWidth;
  unsigned int biHeight;
  unsigned short biPlanes;
  unsigned short biBitCount;
  unsigned int biCompression;
  unsigned int biSizeImage;
  unsigned int biXPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned int biYPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned int biClrUsed;
  unsigned int biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

typedef struct pixel {
  unsigned char intensity;
} PIXEL;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(argc != 4)
   {
    printf("Usage: %s input.bmp output.bmp output.txt\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
   }

   FILE *filePtr;
   FILE *bin;
   FILE *write;
   BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
   BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;
   int i, j;

   write = fopen(argv[3], "w");
   filePtr = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
   bin = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
   if (filePtr == NULL)
   {
    printf("File could not opened\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(bitmapFileHeader), 1, filePtr);
    fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader), 1, filePtr);

    fwrite(&bitmapFileHeader, 1, sizeof(bitmapFileHeader), bin);
    fwrite(&bitmapInfoHeader, 1, sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader), bin);

    int offset = sizeof(bitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader);

    if (bitmapFileHeader.bfType !=0x4D42)
    {
    fclose(filePtr);
    printf("Not a bmp file\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    if(bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount > 8)
    {
    printf("Only for Gray-scale 8 bits per pixel Image\n");
    printf("%s is %u bits per pixel Image\n", argv[1], bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount);
    exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    PIXEL **pixelArray = (PIXEL **)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL*)*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth);

    for(i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++)
    {
    pixelArray[i] = (PIXEL *)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL)*bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight);
    }   

    if (!pixelArray)
    {
    for(i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++)
    {
        free(pixelArray[i]);
    }
    free(pixelArray);
    fclose(filePtr);
    printf("Memory could not be allocated\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight; j++){
        PIXEL pixel;
        fread(&pixel, sizeof(pixel), 1, filePtr);
        fwrite(&pixel, 1, sizeof(pixel), bin);
        pixelArray[i][j].intensity = pixel.intensity;
        fseek(filePtr, sizeof(pixel), SEEK_CUR);
        offset++;
        if(offset == bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage)
            break;
    }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight; j++){
        printf("[%d][%d]:%d", i, j, pixelArray[i][j].intensity);
        fprintf(write, "%d ", pixelArray[i][j].intensity);  
    }
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(write, "\n");
    }


    fclose(filePtr); 
    fclose(write);
    fclose(bin);
    for(i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; i++)
    {
    free(pixelArray[i]);
    }
    free(pixelArray);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is it about the C language that makes their practitioners re-invent reading a image file over and over and over again?

Comment: Have you considered using netpbm (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) or GraphicsMagick (http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) to read the BMP file? They'll take care of all the alignment, byte order, file format version differences, ... issues for you.

Answer (score 2):

Possible problems are:

- you're assuming that `sizeof(PIXEL) == 1` (it may well not be, since it's a struct - you should check) - probably better to change this to a simple typedef anyway
- you're not taking care of row padding (may be a problem if image width is not a multiple of 4)
- there is likely to be a palette, which you're not allowing for

You should check the fields in the BMP header to see what the actual format is, and verify that the size of the data is as expected.

Note also that your error handling for memory allocation failure is broken.